# How big a transition from programmer to modeler/level designer/creator

Tags: c++, animation, models, level-design

So I think I may take a break from the programming side, I have put in 6 hard months learning C++ and graphics theory, I have learned a huge amount but over the last few days have been studying level design and modeling and think that is maybe more suitable to me.

So how would programming compare in a learning curve sense, C++ takes a while to grasp the core language never mind writing 100,000s lines of game engine code which you would eventually have to do.

Without being arrogant the modeling/level creation side seems a much faster progression, is that a fair thing to say?

Comment: You sound like you need to try it. 10 years ago, I started both programming and drawing. Programming clicked and... well, now I immensely respect people who can draw! (More so every day!) Trying to generalise the necessary learning curves is nonsensical though, as they depend on *everything*.

Comment: Please read the [help] for information on what kinds of questions to ask here.

Comment: This is a strange question. It's like comparing poetry to martial arts. I find that I get kicked in the head more often when I practice martial arts but ache more when I write poetry. Anyhow, modeling can be **very** hard if you don't have talent for it and so can programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Level design is not easier.  You may not need a less deep and thorough understanding of each involved topic, but there is much more topics to reckon with.

Roughly you must have notions in :
sculpting, animating, drawing, programming, geometry, esthetics(part of philosophy), applied psychology, artificial intelligence (don't forget the NPCs), architecture and so much more !

If you are a total noob in everything but programming, this will be a huge gap.  The good point is that you can also learn it.  There are many books and websites to help you there.  Also, most topic relevant to game design can be applied to level design and most books about game design discuss level design at some point.

With level design you will soon have to start learning so many things in parallel.  I'm not trying to discourage you though; it is not more difficult than programming either—it mostly depends on your character.  Programming is not smaller either, there so many interesting topics to solve in programming.  In the end, know yourself !